Parameter question of diffuser UNet3DConditionModel
Here the code, the size of text embedding is 77x512 produced by "openai/clip-vit-base-patch32". The input size is 6x128x128.
self.model = UNet3DConditionModel(
        sample_size=128,  
        in_channels=1 + img_channel, 
        out_channels=1,  
        layers_per_block= 2,#3,  
        block_out_channels=(32, 64, 32),
        #encoder_hid_dim = 512,
        cross_attention_dim= 512,
        down_block_types=(
            "DownBlock3D",  # a regular ResNet downsampling block
            "CrossAttnDownBlock3D",  # a ResNet downsampling block with spatial self-attention
            "CrossAttnDownBlock3D",
        ),
        up_block_types=(
            "CrossAttnUpBlock3D",
            "CrossAttnUpBlock3D",  # a ResNet upsampling block with spatial self-attention
            "UpBlock3D",  # a regular ResNet upsampling block
        ),
    )

The error is :
File "D:\ProgramData\anaconda\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\diffusers\models\attention_processor.py", line 534, in head_to_batch_dim
tensor = tensor.reshape(batch_size, seq_len * extra_dim, head_size, dim // head_size)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
diffusers version: 0.30.1
Anyone knows how to set the parameter? Thanks.
